# How to set the charset in request using apache httpclient fluent 4.3.2

Tags: java, character-encoding, request, apache-httpclient-4.x

`Request.config(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, Consts.UTF_8)` and `Request.elementCharset(charset)` are Deprecated.

Now how to set the request charset to utf-8 with fluent?

```java
Request.Post(url)
    .useExpectContinue()
    .version(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
    .bodyString("Important stuff", ContentType.DEFAULT_TEXT)
    .execute().returnContent().asBytes();
```

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to do? Use a non-standard character set for HTTP message elements such as request line and request headers or simply set encoding of the request body?

Comment: I want to send xml to http server, and got the response with that "Cannot encode unknown character set". 

I use wireshark to catch the http request I send, shows that the char set is "iso-8895-1". I need to send the request with charset "utf-8", but could not find how to set it in Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```java
Request.setHeader(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, Consts.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I have tried Request.setHeader("charset", "utf-8") and you mentioned above, but it does not work.

Comment: I use addHeader("Content-Type", "charset=UTF-8") and it works well, thanks

Answer (score 5):

That would be the right way doing it

```
Request.Post("someurl")
        .useExpectContinue()
        .version(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
        .bodyString("Important stuff", ContentType.create("text/plain", Consts.UTF_8))
        .execute()
        .returnContent().asBytes();
```